# Showing a sequence converges almost surely

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $Y\sim Uniform[0,1]$ and let $X_n = Y^n$ Show $\{X_n\}$ converges with probability $1$ to the degenerate random variable $X$ where $P(X=0)=1$

I know the definition of almost sure convergence but I am struggling to see how to apply it in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the event $\Omega' = \{Y<1\}$,
$$
X_n = Y^n\to 0
$$
that is, $$
P(X_n \to 0) \ge P(\Omega').
$$
Let us compute $P(\Omega')$:
$$
P(Y<1) = \int_{[0,1)} dy = 1.
$$
Hence, $P(X_n \to 0)= 1$.

Comment: That's definitely above my skill level. I think there must be another way. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I just say that $X_n\to 0$ whenever $Y<1$ (this is just basic calculus), which happen with probability 1.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: @RobertIsrael That's almost sure convergence, not convergence in probability.