# Convergence of powers of random variables

Tags: probability

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729712/showing-a-sequence-converges-almost-surely), I wonder if the following could be proved (this is probably a Borel-Cantelli trick):

> Let $X_n$ be a family of **independent** random variables with a common density $f$ with respect to the restriction of the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.
>
> In other words, the law of $X_1 = X$ is
>   $$
> P(X\in B) = \int_{[0,1]\cap B} f(x) dx.
> $$
>   Let us define $Y_n = X_n^n$. Then 
>   $$
> Y_n \to 0 \ \ \ \text{a.s.}
> $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, quite the opposite.  For example, consider the uniform distribution.  Then for any $b \in (0,1)$, $$P(Y_n > b) = 
P(X_n > b^{1/n}) = 1-b^{1/n} \approx \dfrac{1}{n} \ln(1/b) \ \text{as}\ n \to \infty$$
Since $\sum_n 1/n = \infty$, Borel-Cantelli says $Y_n > b$ infinitely often.